# Integer array of resource ids returns 0

Tags: java, android, xml, android-drawable, android-resources

I have a set of resource ids stored in an array. This is accessed inside the recycler view to populate an image view. The problem is when I access the array, all values returned is 0.

```
// arrays.xml
<array name="array_category_icons">
    <item>@drawable/autumn</item>
    <item>@drawable/backpack</item>
</array>

// inside recycler view adapter
int[] myIcons = getActivity().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_category_icons);

myIcons[i] always returns 0.
```

The drawables are in the hdpi folder only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do this:

```
TypedArray ta = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.array_category_icons);
Drawable[] icons = new Drawable[ta.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < ta.length(); i++) {
    int id = ta.getResourceId(i, 0);
    if (id != 0) {
        icons[i] = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, id);
    }
}
ta.recycle();
```