# Load all images contained in "drawable-nodpi" folder

Tags: android

I'm working on a simple app in Android and I want to load all the images contained in "drawable-nodpi" folder. I've tried to use this code:

```
public static void load() {
    Field[] ID_Fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();
    int[] resArray = new int[ID_Fields.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < ID_Fields.length; i++) {
        try {
            resArray[i] = ID_Fields[i].getInt(null);
            //System.out.println(ID_Fields[i].getName());
        } catch (...) {...}
    }
}
```

but with `R.drawable.class.getFields()`i cannot select "drawable-nodpi" folder. There is a simple way to do that?

My minSdkVersion is 14

Comment: What use case do you have? You can create an array of integers inside resources, where each value corresponds to an image resource id, then acquire all of them [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43307361/1083957) way. Alternatively, you can keep those resources inside `assets` folder and read those using `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: @azizbekian I want to load all the images in a new `HashMap<String, Bitmap>` where the String is the name (automatically detected) of the image. I'll try keeping resources inside `assets`, but it seems strange that it is not possible to use only the files in the specified folder with `getFields()` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make available the solution that I adopted at the end, here is my code:

```
public static void loadAll() { //called in the app creation phase
    HashMap<String, Integer> tmpHM=new HashMap<>();
    Field[] ID_Fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();
    for(int i = 0; i < ID_Fields.length; i++) {
        try {
            tmpHM.put( ID_Fields[i].getName(), ID_Fields[i].getInt(null));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { }
    }

    database_img= new HashMap<>();
    String[] tmp=Texts.getNamesImg();
    for(String s:tmp){
        database_img.put(s, loadImg(tmpHM.get(s)) );
    }
    //System.out.println("DATABASE: "+database_img.toString());
}

private static Bitmap loadImg(int id){
    bp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),id, null);
    return bp;
}
```

And when i want a specific image, i can find it using the name that i've stored in a static class "Texts":

```
public static Bitmap getImage(String s){ //For example getImage(Texts.LOGO)
    return database_img.get(s);
}
```