# Getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Destination id == 0" aftel call navigate

Tags: android, android-resources, android-architecture-navigation

I'm getting an

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Destination id == 0 can only be used in conjunction with a valid navOptions.popUpTo
```

when I call the code below:

```
override fun onNavigateItemClicked(rIdNavAppSectionItem: Int) {
        findNavController().navigate(rIdNavAppSectionItem)
    }
```

After debug it I figured out that It is calling navigate with rIdNavAppSectionItem == 0.

So, what is the source of my **0** ?

I'm reading resource's ids from array.xml and all my get calls always returns 0.

My res/values/array.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Notice that the android:id value does not include the plus sign in the ID reference,
     because the ID already exists, as defined in the ids.xml -->

    <integer-array name="main_nav_list">
        <item>@id/nav_weighing</item>
        <item>@id/nav_water_intake</item>
        <item>@id/nav_pill_remainder</item>
    </integer-array>

</resources>
```

My res/values/ids.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id -->

<!-- Defines a unique ID. Takes no value, only attributes. -->
<resources>

    <item type="id" name="nav_home" />

    <item type="id" name="nav_weighing" />
    <item type="id" name="nav_water_intake" />
    <item type="id" name="nav_pill_remainder" />

    <item type="id" name="nav_weight_input" />
    <item type="id" name="nav_water_intake_input" />

</resources>
```

And my call is something like:

```
mRootView.context.resources.getIntArray(R.array.main_nav_list)
```

**That return a beautiful array of 0s !!**

Do you know why those ids are not initialized?

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve my issue while I was writing the question:

I don't know why, but I got some similar error before with drawables.

And resolve my past issue with drawables following:
[Integer array of resource ids returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43307243/integer-array-of-resource-ids-returns-0)

So I copy myself :

```
val navigations: TypedArray = mRootView.context.resources.getTypedArray(R.array.main_nav_list)
```

During the for with index:

```
val itWantsToGetAnException: Int = 0
val navigate: Int = navigations.getResourceId(index, itWantsToGetAnException)
```

After use it:

```
navigations.recycle()
```

And no more 0s!! :)

Have a nice Day !!